# Слова "дух", "душа", "одухотворённость", "одушевлённость"

Tags: лингвистика

**Вопрос 1**: При каких условиях слово "дух" и слово "душа" являются синонимами?

**Вопрос 2**: При каких Х предложение "Х одухотворён." равносильно предложению "Х одушевлён."?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, дух и душа - это не синонимы, особенно, если речь идет о религиозном понимании этого вопроса. Христианство рассматривает три составляющие у человека, вспомним книгу св. архиепископа Луки Войноясенецкого "Дух, душа и тело".
Кроме того, слово "дух" может употребляться в гораздо более широком значении, чем "душа". И как содержание, смысл, тема чего-то: "дух приключений", и как понятие бессмертной субстанции, и даже в понятии "запах" (тут еще уместно уменьшительное "душок"): "селедка с душком". Слово же "одухотворение" означает не вселение души в неодушевленный предмет, а, скорее, некий творческий порыв.
Если же говорить о "душе", то она употребляется в значении характеристики одушевления и относится только к конкретному объекту: "у животных тоже есть душа", "у него морская душа" (сравните: "морской дух" мы можем сказать, например, о романе, а о человеке говорим "душа").
При этом понятие "духовность" относится, скорее, к душе. А вот "душевность" — это уже характеристика предмета или человека.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.